# SQL - YTD filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS SQL Server I am trying to filter everything YTD but don't want to hard-code the year in the query since I otherwise will need to maintain on the yearly basis.

Is there a way to filter the query in the WHERE clause that retrieves everything from the beginning of the current year until today?

Basically something like:

```
select * 
from table 
where date between beginningyear and getdate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
where year(date) = year(getdate())
```

A more efficient method would use:

```
where date >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1)
```

Both of these assume no future dates.  But you can easily adapt:

```
where date >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1) and
      date <= getdate()
```